# Set ulimit -n from java

Tags: java, jvm, system-calls, ulimit

I am trying to set ulimit under which my java program runs. Currently, it seems that ulimit -n is set to 4096 because when I run this code (which is a part of my java program), it outputs 4096.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "ulimit -n");
try {
  Process process = processBuilder.start();
  // Prints 4096.
  LOGGER_.info(getStringFromInputStream(process.getInputStream()));
} catch (IOException e) {
  // The flow does not reach this catch block.
  LOGGER_.error("exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Is it possible to change it to something else, say 8192? I tried this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder2 = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "ulimit -n 8192");
try {
  Process process = processBuilder2.start();
  LOGGER_.error("starting agent2...");
  LOGGER_.error(getStringFromInputStream(process.getInputStream()));
} catch (IOException e) {
  LOGGER_.error("exception caught2: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

and

```
try {
  String[] cmdString = new String[3];
  cmdString[0] = "/bin/bash";
  cmdString[1] = "-c";
  cmdString[2] = "ulimit -n 8192";
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdString);
  LOGGER_.error(getStringFromInputStream(process.getInputStream()));
} catch (IOException e) {
  LOGGER_.error("exception caught:" + e.getMessage());
}
```

But I am not sure if these are the correct way to do so. Also, if the ulimit -n is even getting modified or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ulimit` command updates the limits of the *current* process and all inherited processes. When you invoke `ulimit` using `Runtime.exec` or `ProcessBuilder`, it starts a new process and updates the limits of this *new* process with no effect on current Java process.

In order to apply new limits on itself, Java process should call [`setrlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) function in its own context. Since there is no Java wrapper for this function, it can be called only via a native interface: JNI, JNA or JNR.

However, if Java runs under unprivileged user, updating file limit (`ulimit -n`) is useless anyway, because HotSpot JVM updates this limit to maximum allowed value automatically - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487284/how-and-when-and-where-jvm-change-the-max-open-files-value-of-linux).

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround that works. I was using a shell script that executed the java program. So, I set the ulimit before the shell script executed the running-the-java part. As answered by @apangin, this set the ulimit of the shell process and the java process that spawned from this shell process, inherited this ulimit.